# I'm trying to figure out MySQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

How can I get top 3 records with maximum score sum and price sum add up to a certain value( for ex 25 or less than 25).This is my table

CREATE TABLE `test_1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Spiller` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Score` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pris` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (1,'a1' ,7.87 ,11.6);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (2,'a2' ,8.32 ,10.4);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (3,'a3' ,6.32 ,11.6);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (4,'a4' ,4.15 ,8.5);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (5,'a5' ,4.5 ,8.5);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (6,'a6' ,11.13 ,12.5);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (7,'a7' ,8.12 ,10.4);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (8,'a8' ,5.21 ,7.5);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (9,'a9' ,3.77 ,7);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (10,'a10' ,4.38 ,5.6);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (11,'a11' ,2.69 ,5.6);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (12,'a12' ,4.48 ,7.4);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (13,'a13' ,3.47 ,5.6);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (14,'a14' ,4.87 ,6);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (15,'a15' ,4.6 ,6.6);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (16,'a16' ,2.74,6.3);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (17,'a17' ,5.54 ,10.4);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (18,'a18' ,3.86 ,7.2);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (19,'a19' ,6.4 ,5);
INSERT INTO `test`.`test_1`(`id`,`Spiller`,`Score`,`Pris`) VALUES (20,'a20' ,2.94 ,5.9);

and i want the result like this.Thanks in advance :)

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQKWs.png)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Do you want the top 3 scored records?  Or three records that add up to 25?

Comment: three records that add up to 25

Comment: Add sample table data as formatted text, not images. And the expected result too.

Comment: What if there aren't three records that add up to 25?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I would like to get an output 25 or less than 25

Answer (score 2):

I guess something like this

```
select r1.spiller, r2.spiller, r3.spiller
from pris r1
join pris r2 on r1.spiller > r2.spiller
join pris r3 on r2.spiller > r3.spiller 
where r1.pris + r2.pris + r3.pris = 25;
```

which can be turned into a top-3

```
select r1.spiller, r2.spiller, r3.spiller, r1.pris+r2.pris+r3.pris 
from pris r1
join pris r2 on r1.spiller > r2.spiller -- self-join, use > on the primary key to avoid duplicates
join pris r3 on r2.spiller > r3.spiller 
where r1.pris + r2.pris + r3.pris <= 25
order by r1.pris+r2.pris+r3.pris desc
limit 3;
```

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE pris (
  spiller varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  pris decimal(4,1) DEFAULT NULL
);


insert into 
pris(spiller, pris)
values 
('a1', 11.6), ('a2', 10.4), ('a3', 11.6),
('a4', 8.5), ('a5', 8.5), ('a6', 12.5),
('a7', 8.4), ('a8', 7.5),('a9', 7),
('a10', 7.6), ('a11', 5.6), ('a12', 7.4),
('a13', 5.6), ('a14', 6), ('a15', 6.6),
('a16', 6.3), ('a17', 10.4), ('a18', 7.2),
('a19', 5), ('a20', 5.9);
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------+---------+------+
| spiller | spiller | spiller |  sum |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
| a8      | a6      | a19     | 25.0 |
| a8      | a20     | a1      | 25.0 |
| a18     | a17     | a12     | 25.0 |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
```

Comment: It return lots of rows , but i want only 3 records

Comment: @Priya I think it's the principal that counts, you should really work out the details yourself

Comment: Thanks , Can we make it possible to return 3 Spillers(Players) row wise and next columns with other deatails

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r1.Spiller, r2.Spiller, r3.Spiller
FROM MyTable as r1, MyTable as r2, MyTable as r3
WHERE r1.Pris+r2.Pris+r3.Pris = 25
```

Comment: it will return dupliicates in spiller for case records with pris = [5, 15]

Comment: @VladBochenin yes: it will return a lot of things

Comment: Yes you r right, but I want result 25 or less than 25. If result not equal to 25 then it gives next 3 records less than 25.Sorry i forgot to explain earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is to select 3 rows which has most higher "Pris"

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY Pris DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Edit: I understood question wrongly, but to select highest "Pris"ed 3 rows, this might be your answer, but this is not the answer for your question

Comment: Yes, ofcourse not. I want 3 records from the table whose sum either equal to 25 or less than 25.